# Cannot initschema dbType Derby for Hive 2.3.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Cannot init schema dbType Derby

```
hduser1@knime:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.6-bin/bin$ schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:4045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:4008)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.<init>(HiveSchemaTool.java:82)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. This is due to version mismatch in gauva jar files in Hadoop common libraries and hive libraries.
2. As per my installation location below are the commands executed.
   step1: copied the hive jar file in local by below command.

   sudo cp /usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.6/lib/guava-14.0.1 homehduser1/hivejar

step2: after the backup of old jar file execute below command to move latest jar file from Hadoop to hive lib folder

```
cp /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-27.0-jre.jar /usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.6-bin/lib
```

Comment: Am I supposed to do something else after copying the guava-file? Still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue.

Comment: Gotta rename the old version of guava jar